# error with % operator inside closure

Tags: rust

This code

```
let vec = vec![1, 3, 4, 5, 6];
for i in vec.iter().filter(|x| x % 2 == 0) {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

Produces the error

```
<anon>:4:36: 4:37 error: binary operation `%` cannot be applied to type `&&_` [E0369]
<anon>:4     for i in vec.iter().filter(|x| x % 2 == 0) {
                                            ^
```

I cannot understand the meaning of this error. Is this related to how the anonymous closure structure is created by the compiler?

The following code seems to be working.

```
for i in vec.iter().filter(|&x| x % 2 == 0) {
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not related to how closure structure is created, it is a simple type error.

`vec.iter()`, when `vec: Vec<T>`, returns an iterator which yields references to its elements. `filter()` closure also accepts each element by reference (because otherwise elements would be consumed but this would defeat the whole purpose of `filter()`). Therefore, in `vec.iter().filter(|x| ...)` the closure argument `x` has type `&&T`, in your case, `&&i32`.

Rust numeric operators can't be applied to `&&T`, only to `&T` or `T`, so you need to dereference the closure argument somehow. There are two ways, first, as you noticed, you can use dereference pattern:

```
vec.iter().filter(|&x| x % 2 == 0)
// or even
vec.iter().filter(|&&x| x % 2 == 0)
```

Dereference pattern automatically dereferences the reference it is matching:

```
&x: &&i32   ==>  x: &i32
&&x: &&i32  ==>  x: i32
```

Alternatively, you can dereference the number directly:

```
vec.iter().filter(|x| *x % 2 == 0)
// or
vec.iter().filter(|x| **x % 2 == 0)
```